# How to replace values between two curly brackets in python?

Tags: python, django

I want to replace values in strings between two curly brackets.

e.g:

```
string  = f"""
my name is {{name}} and I'm {{age}} years old
"""
```

Now I want to replace name, and age by some values.

```
render_param = {
"name":"AHMED",
"age":20
}
```

so the final output should be.

```
my name is AHMED and I'm 20 years old.
```

Comment: and why exactly are you doubling up the {{}} and use f-strings? you are not formatting anything into the f.string you provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with the template render engine with:

```
from django.template import Template, Context

template = Template("my name is {{ name }} and I'm {{ age }} years old")
render_param = {
    'name':'AHMED',
    'age':20
}
result = template.render(Context(render_param))
```

Comment: `Cannot assign "<django.template.base.Template object at 0x7efce47d0460>": "Email.html_template_id" must be a "EmailTemplate" instance.`  this error is raising

Comment: @FlashMaddy: you seem to assign this to some model object. You need to work with the `result` and somehow wrap this then in an `EmailTemplate` object...

Answer (score 3):

If you really want that with Python, regular expressions can do it:

```
import re

render_param = {
"name":"AHMED",
"age":20
}

string  = f"""
my name is {{name}} and I'm {{age}} years old
"""

print(re.sub("{(.*?)}",lambda m:str(render_param[m.group(1)]),string))
```

results in

> ```
> my name is AHMED and I'm 20 years old.
> ```

But of course if you have django anyway, use its built-in feature as shown in the other answer.