# How to replace special text with other special text - Python

Tags: python, django

How do I change my special string to a different value if value appears?

My variables

```
special_url = http://127.0.0.1:8000/
text = '...'
special_symbol = {{URL}}
```

Well i have text like this:

```
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more- 

{{URL}}

Or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here',
```

I need change above text to this when the value `{{URL}}` is in `text`

```
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more- 

http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here',
```

I try this, bot now work:

```
massage = re.sub('{{URL}}', obj.special_url, text)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace values between two curly brackets in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72257354/how-to-replace-values-between-two-curly-brackets-in-python)

Comment: this answer is really useful, but If I good understand it, you can't figure out the replacement pattern yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need regexes at all, python strings have a built-in `.replace()` method:

```py
original = "link: {{URL}}"
special_symbol = "{{URL}}"
to_replace = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"

new_string = original.replace(special_symbol, to_replace)
new_string # "link: http://127.0.0.1:8000/"
```